# A - B is semidefinite, what the relationship about their eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis, nonnegative-matrices

$A, B$ are two symmetric matrices, if $ A-B $ is semidefinite (i.e.$ A - B \geq 0$), if we rearrange the eigenvalues of two matrices, $\lambda_1 (A) \geq \lambda_2 (A) \geq ... \geq \lambda_n (A)$, and the same for $ B $, can we say $ \lambda_i (A) \geq \lambda_i (B) $ for each $i$ ?

Comment: Horn and Johnson, *Matrix Analysis*, Corollary 7.7.4.

Comment: $A \ge B \implies \lambda_i(A) \ge \lambda_i(B)$.